# Adding pair in set

Tags: c++, set, std-pair

I am trying to insert pair of int and string in my set. What i am trying to do is implement a hash map using sets, I am storing the number and its corresponding string using store function and then retrieving the string using retrieve. Please suggest what is the problem and is there any way it can be done more efficiently. The error is in store function. I have not written main function as its just taking input and calling the functions.

```
typedef pair<int, string> pairs;
pairs p;
set<pairs> s;
set<pairs>::iterator it;
int i=0;

void store(int num,string s) 
{
p[i].first=num;   //error is while I am using the pair to store the string
p[i].second=s;
s.insert(p[i]);
i++;
}

string retrieve(int num)
{
for(it=s.begin();it!=s.end();++it)
{
    pairs m = *it;
    if(m.first==num)
    {
        return m.second;
    }
}
}
```

My error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘pairs {aka std::pair<int, std::basic_string<char> >}’ and ‘int’)
  p[i].first=num;
```

Comment: `std::pair` doesn't have an indexing `operator[]`. What's actually unclear about the error message?

Comment: Also, why don't you just use `std::map<int, std::string>` or `std::unordered_map<int, string>` - will make the `retrieve` function *much* faster!

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes maps can be used but I was trying to use pairs to implements in set just out of curiosity to see how they work, but I am having some problems trying to resolve them.

Comment: Thanks for help I resolved the error, you want pairs to represent a collection of pairs, you need to make your pairs a container. so, what I needed was to first declare its size as pairs p[100];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pairs` is a type alias for `pair<int, string>`. [`std::pair` does not have an `operator[]` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Assuming you want `pairs` to represent a collection of pairs, you need to make your `pairs` a container *(e.g. a `vector` or an `array`)*.

As [Martin Bonner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771073/martin-bonner) noted in the comment, the symbol `s` inside `store` refers to the `string s` parameter. Change it to avoid clashing with `set s`'s identifier.

```
typedef pair<int, string> pairs[100];
pairs p;

void store(int num, string str) 
{    
    p[i].first=num;  
    p[i].second=str;
    s.insert(p[i]);
    i++;   
}
```

Comment: This still won't work, because the call to `s.insert` will try and call the `insert` function of the second argument to `store`, rather than of the global set of pairs.

Comment: Good catch. Improving the answer.

Comment: Also, there is no real point in storing the pairs externally to the set - just write `void store( int num, std::string str) { s.insert({num,str}); }`

Comment: @MartinBonner: yeah, the whole program has a very poor architecture. But I think that's out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @PrashantShubham: then carefully read your error and use the internet and your learning resources to try solving it. If you still have trouble, post the error here or on a new question if appropriate.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I will try to resolve the error, thanks for help.